# Shape File To Convert Realtion tag in OSM Data

Tags: openstreetmap, graphhopper

I am Routing Working routing application which is working in osm data but i have data in shape file so by using JOSM i convert in to OSM data but i have another file for turn restriction where i have get to , form and Junction data  so how to implement in to osm file

Comment: You need to merge your data into the OSM file or feed GraphHopper with a custom import of your turn restriction file. See e.g. here on how to do that in Java https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/graphhopper/reader/OSMReader.java#L476

Comment: @karussell  for turn restriction there are need to relation tag and tag have to ,form and via value  so via wll be juction so it will complementary to need add junction node